Elasticsearch aggregation name syntax documented somewhere?
I got the error message
Aggregation names can contain any character except '[', ']', and '>'

from Elasticsearch when a ">" somehow ended up in an aggregation name. Is that documented somewhere?

This limitation is coming from bucket path syntax so it is implicitly documented there. You should be able to use anything that doesn't clash with that syntax. Based on the implementation the error message is correct.
The only other limitation that is unlikely to affect you is _mvt_ prefix for aggregations used in vector tile API. It shouldn't affect aggregation names in all other contexts.
